# how to get xmlns attribute value in JAVA using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I need to get the value of an xmlns attribute using JAXB, but @XmlAttribute returns null.
How can I do this for example from here:

```
<test xmlns="testAttribute" />
```

I thought this was enough:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {
  
  @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
  private String attribute;
}
```

For any other attribute name this works, but not for "xmlns".